# A CTE runs well in SQL Server but does not work in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, oracle, common-table-expression

I am learning CTE in Oracle, and I have written a SQL statement with a CTE. I didn't find any error in this SQL in SQL Server database, but it always causes an error in Oracle 11g database;

```
CREATE TABLE EMP 
   (    EMPNO numeric(4,0), 
    ENAME VARCHAR(10 ), 
    JOB VARCHAR(9 ), 
    MGR numeric(4,0), 
    HIREDATE DATE, 
    SAL numeric(7,2), 
    COMM numeric(7,2), 
    DEPTNO numeric(2,0)
   )

Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,getdate(),800,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,getdate(),1600,300,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,getdate(),1250,500,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,getdate(),2975,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,getdate(),1250,1400,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,getdate(),2850,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,getdate(),2450,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,getdate(),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',null,getdate(),5000,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,getdate(),1500,0,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,getdate(),1100,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,getdate(),950,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,getdate(),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,getdate(),1300,null,10);


select * from emp;


WITH SCOTT_EMP AS(
SELECT EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,0 T FROM EMP WHERE MGR IS NULL
UNION all
SELECT E.EMPNO,E.MGR,E.ENAME,M.T+1 FROM EMP E
INNER JOIN SCOTT_EMP M ON E.MGR=M.EMPNO
)
SELECT * FROM SCOTT_EMP;
```

Comment: can you show your error message please

Comment: I think I have an idea of the error. But with a error message provided it should be easier. By the way, pls try to add the column specification to your with. WITH SCOTT_EMP(EMPNO,MGR,ENAME, T) AS ...

Comment: At first view and without further information: Missing semicolon after `create table`-statement...At second view: In oracle it is `sysdate`not `getdate()`

Comment: @Ionic is right, this query gives `ORA-32039`, adding `(EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,T)` in first line solves it.

Comment: Well then my guess was correct. Just for future questions. I'll add the answer seperate below.

Comment: It is a simple hierarchical query. `select empno, mgr, ename, level - 1 as T
  from emp
  START WITH mgr IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
  order by t, empno;`

Comment: @LalitKumarB the SQL I provided is used for SQL server , not for Oracle , because EMP table already exists in Oracle 11g database.

Comment: @Ionic the answer you provided doesn't work in Oracle 11g database.

Comment: @davegreen100 the error message as below after I add alias.SQL> WITH SCOTT_EMP(EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,T) AS(
  2      SELECT EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,0 T FROM EMP WHERE MGR IS NULL
  3      UNION all
  4      SELECT E.EMPNO,E.MGR,E.ENAME,M.T+1 FROM EMP E
  5      INNER JOIN SCOTT_EMP M ON E.MGR=M.EMPNO
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM SCOTT_EMP;
WITH SCOTT_EMP(EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,T) AS(
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing


SQL>

Comment: @LorenZhan The query I gave should be what you need to use in Oracle. Or do you only want a query using WITH clause.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the columns in your CTE expression. In SQL Server this is just an optional property. In 11g you'll need to define them. Change your code to this:

```
WITH SCOTT_EMP(EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,T) AS(
    SELECT EMPNO,MGR,ENAME,0 T FROM EMP WHERE MGR IS NULL
    UNION all
    SELECT E.EMPNO,E.MGR,E.ENAME,M.T+1 FROM EMP E
    INNER JOIN SCOTT_EMP M ON E.MGR=M.EMPNO
)
SELECT * FROM SCOTT_EMP;
```

Comment: @lonic I have tried the method you provide, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can use `start with connect by` to achieve the same result, no need to use nested query

Preparation

```
CREATE TABLE EMP 
   (    EMPNO numeric(4,0), 
    ENAME VARCHAR(10 ), 
    JOB VARCHAR(9 ), 
    MGR numeric(4,0), 
    HIREDATE DATE, 
    SAL numeric(7,2), 
    COMM numeric(7,2), 
    DEPTNO numeric(2,0)
   );

Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,sysdate,800,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,sysdate,1600,300,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,sysdate,1250,500,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,sysdate,2975,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,sysdate,1250,1400,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,sysdate,2850,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,sysdate,2450,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,sysdate,3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',null,sysdate,5000,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,sysdate,1500,0,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,sysdate,1100,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,sysdate,950,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,sysdate,3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,sysdate,1300,null,10);
```

Query:

```
select empno, mgr, ename, level - 1 as T
  from emp
  start with mgr is null
  connect by prior empno = mgr;
```

Output:

```
| EMPNO |    MGR |  ENAME | T |
|-------|--------|--------|---|
|  7839 | (null) |   KING | 0 |
|  7566 |   7839 |  JONES | 1 |
|  7788 |   7566 |  SCOTT | 2 |
|  7876 |   7788 |  ADAMS | 3 |
|  7902 |   7566 |   FORD | 2 |
|  7369 |   7902 |  SMITH | 3 |
|  7698 |   7839 |  BLAKE | 1 |
|  7499 |   7698 |  ALLEN | 2 |
|  7521 |   7698 |   WARD | 2 |
|  7654 |   7698 | MARTIN | 2 |
|  7844 |   7698 | TURNER | 2 |
|  7900 |   7698 |  JAMES | 2 |
|  7782 |   7839 |  CLARK | 1 |
|  7934 |   7782 | MILLER | 2 |
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I know it's correct. but I now learn about CTE. so I need to know what errors happen in my SQL.